# Partial URL redirect with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm need to redirect a a bunch of URL's through mod_rewrite. The URL structure is as follows:

```
www.mysite.com/somescript.php?&lang=asp&variable1&variable2
```

Needs to redirect to

```
www.mysite.com/somescript.php?&lang=php&variable1&variable2
```

So, basically, any URL with **&lang=asp** in it needs to be redirected to exactly the same URL but with **&lang=php** replacing **&lang=asp**.

Is there a way I can do this through .htaccess, perhaps with some sort of wildcard?

Thanks alot, I would appreciate your help.

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the Query String

Change any single instance of val in the query string to other_val when accessing /path. Note that %1 and %2 are back-references to the matched part of the regular expression in the previous RewriteCond.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)lang=asp(.*)$
RewriteRule /path /path?%lang=php%2
```

Read this page for more info http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: Shouldn't the regular expression be `^(.*)(?:^|&)lang=asp(?:&|$)(.*)$`? It doesn't look as elegant, but it only matches at the boundaries, so `slang=aspect-oriented` goes through it unchanged.